# How do you find the time dependent equation of motion here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> Find the position of a mass $m$ rotating in a vertical circle at the end of a string length $\ell$ in a uniform gravitational field, for any value of time $t$, given initial position and velocity.

Every attempt I have made so far results in a function v(r) or v(theta), neither of which I am able to make time dependent.

Comment: Please add further details to your question, especially, a brief version of your own calculations. See also this meta post, < http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714 >, in order to compose a good question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Your exercise is a homework exercise, and we do not have enough context to know what you are asking. Surprising, the full treatment of the pendulum motion for arbitrary positions is quite complex, involving elliptic integrals (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_%28mathematics%29#Arbitrary-amplitude_period) if you want more details) and beyond college level. You probably want to assume some approximation (small angles) to have a reasonable solution.

Comment: I understand that this question is a complex one most likely beyond my scope, but it is something that has been bugging me for a while. At the least could you point me in the direction of a general procedure to solve for the equation of motion of a system? In all but the most simple cases I get stuck on a step where dtheta/dt depends on theta.

Answer (score 1):

From conservation of energy you can arrive at $v = \ell \dot{\theta}$ as a function of position angle $\theta$. Time is found with the following integral

$$ t = \int \frac{1}{\dot{\theta}}\,{\rm d}\theta $$

### Edit 1

If you call $\theta$ the angle from horizontal of the mass you can derive 
$$ \begin{align} \ddot{\theta} & = -\frac{m g \cos \theta}{r} \\
K & =\frac{g \sin \theta}{r} + \frac{1}{2} \dot\theta^2 
\end{align} $$

To be truthful, I don't understand why they are asking for this. The result is an elliptic integral since speed is $$\dot{\theta} = \sqrt{2 K  -\frac{2 g \sin\theta}{r}}$$ (with $K$ some constant from init. conditions) and $$t = \int \frac{b}{\sqrt{1-a^2 \sin \theta}}\,{\rm d}\theta$$ with $a^2 = \frac{g}{K r}$ and $b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 K}}$

This integral involves the elliptic integral of the first kind according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+b%2Fsqrt%281+-a%5E2+sin%28x%29%29).

Comment: Thanks @ja72, but dtheta/dt isn't constant and I am having trouble applying this.